# Question about limit distance constraint. This constraint can't use a cube shape as a target object?

Tags: constraints

I have a question about limit distance constraint.
I've read this page
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/transform/limit_distance.html

it says sphere again and again. I would like to use a cube as a target object of limit distance constraint,but limit distance area made by target object is not cube shape, but spherical area. Limit distance constraint can't use a cube shape as its own shape?

And If it is only spherical area,is there any way to see the actual target object area? I guess it uses object's bounds area so I need to change target object's Viewport display option ? I see its spherical bounds, If I activate "Display as Bounds - Bounds Sphere". Is this the actual limit distance area?

Comment: No, it's not using object bounds, it's using the origin point. And since the origin has no faces pointing in certain directions like a cube, it's always a spherical distance. And displaying the object's bounds will do exactly that, display its bounds. And the bounds of an object are the maximum dimensions of the mesh, not the influence range of any modifier.

Comment: I see. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Make a cube, make it non-rendering, bone parent it to something.

Use a shrinkwrap constraint on the limited bone targeting the cube.  Mode depends on limit distance mode you want: inside, outside, or surface.

[image]

Depending on your specifics, there may be other ways to do this (like 6 floor constraints if you want to limit distance/inside, or Chris's solution if you want to limit distance from parent or parent of parent) but when we're talking about a cube, a shrinkwrap is performant and without any interpolation problems.

Comment: Nice. Thank you for your answer.